# How can I make a systemd service start after the *completion* of another service?

Tags: systemd

I always run into cases where I need a program associated with service A to run to completion before service B. "After" does not scratch this itch. After says

> Most importantly, for service units start-up is considered completed for the purpose of Before=/After= when all its configured start-up commands have been invoked and they either failed or reported start-up success.", **but that doesn't imply the underlying process has successfully completed.**

Kind of a glaring hole in functionality IMO. How can I start service B if it relies on the successful completion of Service A?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1072165

Comment: That's a pretty helpful illustration of an empirical assessment, but the answer itself doesn't point to the relevant paragraph within the document. It is possible to deduce the correct answer from your link though, so I'll post an answer and make it more clear. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1072165) almost clearly answers my question, but leaves out a relevant description of `Type=oneshot`. Here's the relevant text from [the systemd.service documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html).

> Behavior of oneshot is similar to simple; however, the service manager will consider the unit up after the main process exits. It will then start follow-up units.

So one can use oneshot services for deterministic ordering.

Answer (score 0):

That's solved inherently by `Requires=` which you usually use when you use `After=`; citing `man systemd.unit`:

> Requires=
>
> Similar to Wants=, but declares a stronger requirement dependency. Dependencies of this type may also be configured by adding a symlink to a .requires/ directory accompanying the unit file.
>
> If this unit gets activated, the units listed will be activated as well. If one of the other units fails to activate, and an ordering dependency After= on the failing unit is set, this unit will not be started.
> Besides, with or without specifying After=, this unit will be stopped (or restarted) if one of the other units is explicitly stopped (or restarted).

`After=` just specifies the point in time when your unit will be started in relation to the unit you rely on, and `Requires=` defines that you need the other unit to be successfully started at that point.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I'm looking for "After service x completes, then service y can start". Requires just says the dependencies will be "activated", not "after their completion"

Comment: Also, a successful start does not imply a successful finish

Comment: @DeepDeadpool I'm under the expression the service you depend on might have the wrong `Type=` then! Could you maybe illustrate what kind of service we're talking about?

Comment: I learned that oneshot services allow for deterministic ordering and posted an answer pointing to the relevant documentation. Thank you for looking at the question, regardless.

If this is not polite, feel free to alter your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @DeepDeadpool I don't know whether it's polite, but you're being nice about it, so I can't complain!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the objective is it interferes with shutdown.  This is why you're having such trouble finding an answer.  If `shutdown.target` is raised, then your service will stop, but that will try to trigger your follow-up service.

---

If your first job is short-running, then consider combining them into one service with [`Type=simple`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#Type=), and running it with [`ExecStartPre=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=).  The system will remain `activating` until the first job is done, and it will only execute the second job if the first was successful.  This style is useful if the first job should do a setup for the second job.

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/path/to/firstjob
ExecStart=/path/to/secondjob

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If the second job is also short-running, then use [`Type=oneshot`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#Type=).  In this case, both jobs can be [`ExecStart=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=).

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/firstjob
ExecStart=/path/to/secondjob

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If the first job isn't short-running, but the second is, then consider running the second job in [`ExecStopPost=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#ExecStopPost=).  But do be careful because this command regardless of whether the `ExecStart=` was successful.  You can wrap your second job in a script, conditionally running it based on the success of the first job by checking   [`$SERVICE_RESULT`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html#%24SERVICE_RESULT), [`$EXIT_CODE` and `$EXIT_STATUS`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html#%24EXIT_CODE).  This paradime is particularly useful if the second job is a cleanup task.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/firstjob
ExecStopPost=/bin/bash -c "[ $SERVICE_RESULT = success ] && /path/to/secondjob"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If both jobs are long-running, then you'll need to get more creative.  One thing you could do is to set up a trigger with a [`*.path`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.path.html) unit.  That would trigger its sister service when [`PathChanged=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.path.html#PathExists=) is touched.  For the path, I'd use something unique, and prefixed with the [`%t` specifier](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers) to put this file in `/run`:

```
# A.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/firstjob
ExecStopPost=/bin/bash -c "[ $SERVICE_RESULT = success ] && touch %t/B.trigger"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# B.path
[Path]
PathChanged=%t/B.trigger
Service=B.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# B.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/secondjob
```

This wont interfere with shutdown because the path will be stopped before triggering the next unit.